# How to insert into time div?

Tags: php, time

Hey I was wondering how can I insert into my time a div?

So here is the code that I am working with :

```
";

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo(date("F j, Y, a"));

echo "
```

I was hoping to find if anybody knows the code to make it look like this:

```
";

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo(date("F j, Y,[<div id='txt'></div>] a"));

echo "
```

I placed a :

```
<div id='txt'></div>
```

right in the middle of the time format, that is not working what would be a way of doing it right?

Comment: Please correct your code, we cannot really understand its function here...

Comment: Yea its a <div id='txt'></div> in the middle of the code, thanks corrected

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo(date("F j, Y,"));
echo '<div id="txt">';
echo(date("a"));
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`[<div id='txt'></div>]` contains a looooot of metacharacters related to time format. [All these letters](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php) are taken and must be escaped.

Either use separate date() calls (cf Tu Hoang's answer) or escape everything :

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date("F j, Y,[<\d\iv \i\d='\tx\t'></\d\iv>] a");
?>
```

Pretty sure I forgot one...

**Edit :** I've tested my above code, works.